# Decomposition using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Using Lagrange multipliers, decompose the number 411 in the sum of three (possibly fractional) nonnegative numbers, making sure that their product is maximized.

Determine whether the solution is a global maximum, and justify.

- the problem I'm facing is more on how to decompose the number using Larange multipliers. I'm new to the topic so I have no idea how to even start.

Comment: "Decompose into a sum" means you'll have $x+y+z=411$. "Maximize their product" means $xyz$ should be maximized. Now setting up the problem is essentially applying a formula: $\nabla(xyz)=\lambda \nabla(x+y+z)$. Solving the problem may or may not be simple, it depends on the problem.

Comment: One common theme in dealing with Lagrange multiplier problems is determining whether you need to know what $\lambda$ is. In this problem you don't, because you can translate the Lagrange multiplier equation into $xy=yz=xz$.

Comment: Oh, I kinda get it now. But from the application of the formula, do you mean ∇(xyz)=-λ∇(x+y+z) ? From what I was taught, I should first get ∇(xyz)+λ∇(x+y+z)=0. Also, when you get xy=yz=xz, how do you use that to get the three nonnegative numbers?

Comment: The sign convention for $\lambda$ has no effect on the solution. As for your other question, let's look at the first part. That says $xy=yz$. Certainly $y \neq 0$, because there is a solution with a positive product (such as $[411/3,411/3,411/3]$). So we can divide by $y$ and get $x=z$. If you do this again with the other part you find $y=x$. Now what?

Comment: (More rigorously you would break up into cases: the first equation would give "either $y=0$ or $x=z$", the second would give "either $z=0$ or $x=y$", and the third would give "either $x=0$ or $y=z$". But the critical points where one of the variables is zero are *not* maxima.)